# Дочерний элемент криво распирает родителя

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять почему у меня при масштабировании страницы потомок распирает родителя так, что тот перестает доходить до конца страницы. Выглядит это так:

Я попробовал выложить код на https://jsfiddle.net/t7pvewLr/ но там оно не воспроизводится. Проще посмотреть на реального [сайта](http://shm.code123.org).

Вот так объявлен центральный блок Central в который LeftSideContent и RightSide вписаны:

```
.MainContainer {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.Central {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.LeftSide {
  background-color: #ddd0d1;
  flex-grow: 8;

}
.RightSide{
  background-color: #965254;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

В чем причина? Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема тут:

```
.MainContainer { height: 100vh }
```

И дело не в масштабировании, а в переполнении колонок — когда контента становится больше, чем на один вьюпорт, он начинает вылазить за родителя, а сам родитель не увеличивается.